# Spring security 3.2: Does a custom UserDetails & UserDetailsService need a custom AuthenticationManager?

Tags: authentication, service, spring-security

I'm working with spring security 3.2, JSF2 , Hibernate4.

I'have done 3/4 of the work :) but my authentication system doesn't work yet.

I have a UserService who implements UserDetailsService, a domain Class User who implements UserDetails.

THe login system never stop user to access secured pages, i tried user name and password who doesn't exist in my database...

Thanks for the help.

I have a loginBean who is trying to authenticate the user when he connects via login form :

> 

```
public String login() {

        try {

            Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

        return "secured";
    }
```

My spring security looks like this :

```
`<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Admin" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/" >    </security:form-login>
    </security:http>

   <!-- User Data Access Object -->
   <beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.dao.UserDaoImpl" >
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
   </beans:bean>

     <!-- User Business Object -->
   <beans:bean id="userBo" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.bo.UserBoImpl" >
        <beans:property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
   </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="login" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.beans.LoginBean" scope ="request">
         <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
     </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="standardPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userBo" >
            <security:password-encoder ref="standardPasswordEncoder"/>   
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>`
```

This is the error who show up...

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: 1
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at com.clb.genomic.lyon.beans.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:47).....

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.clb.genomic.lyon.dao.UserDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:59)
    at com.clb.genomic.lyon.bo.UserBoImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserBoImpl.java:68)
    at com.clb.genomic.lyon.bo.UserBoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9ea98abf.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204).....
```

Comment: `intercept-url` should contain `pattern=/Admin/**` to match also subresources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception from stack trace shows you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and it seems that you are reading from an empty array.

You should also check what value is being passed to `loadUserByUsername()` method, and if that user exists.

Comment: Yeah that's what you said...The value passed in loadUserByUsername was not good...Thanks a lot , you help to resolve my bug.:)